# Django/Vue -> Heroku: Static files not loading at production server

Tags: python, django, vue.js, heroku

Static files load when `DEBUG=True` (locally and at the dev server), but not when `DEBUG=False` (production).

`STATICFILES_DIRS` is set to my `dist` dir created by Vue, and `dist` is not in the `.gitignore`. Heroku runs collectstatic on every deploy by default (I have not changed this).

The actual error is a 404 when trying to load any static file. The `whitenoise` package is being used. I've updated the middleware settings, and `wsgi.py` according to the docs, and have the settings variable which enables compression via `whitenoise` set (also according to the `whitenoise` docs).

`whitenoise` usually works fine with other apps. I'm not sure what's wrong with this. The difference is that I'm using Vue for the first time. I'd never used a js framework before.

When setting `DEBUG=False` locally, staticfiles still load fine, so I am unable to debug in that way.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-heroku was the problem. In my settings I was using django-heroku. Removing it got staticfiles to load at production.